# Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Tags: java

Receiving the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater at Tuto.OneDimArrays.main(OneDimArrays.java:14)
```

CODE:

```
public class OneDimArrays {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int[] xabc = new int[5];    
        xabc[2]=20;    
        xabc[0]=50;    
        for(int temp:xabc){    
        System.out.println(temp);   
        }
    }
}
```

Please help..

Comment: It means what it says.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then right click on the project, goto properties, Java Compiler, Check Enable project specific settings and set the Compiler compliance level to greater than 1.5. I solved this issue by setting it to 1.6.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Although the output is self-explanatory but yours can be a potential solution especially today as we all are above JAVA 1.5, atleast most of us are.

Comment: Slight correction, 1.5 works too. Since it's 1.5 or greater (inclusive).

Comment: I have it set at version 10 and I have the problem

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is. You are using a for-each loop:

```
for(int temp : xabc)
{
    System.out.println(temp);   
}
```

This syntax was only added in Java 1.5, so you appear to be compiling using an earlier version. Without knowing what IDE/environment you're using, I can't tell you how to fix this, but see if you can find a way to compile your code using a more up-to-date version of java.

Note that there is a difference between the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and the JDK (Java Development Kit). The JRE is used to run java programs on your computer, while the JDK is used to write java programs on your computer. Normally your system only warns you when the JRE is outdated (as most computer users don't write code and probably don't even have the JDK installed). Therefore, even if your JRE is up to date, you won't be able to compile the latest features unless you have the right JDK.

If you're using an old JDK, you can download the latest version [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp).

If you're using an up-to-date JDK, you will have to change some settings in your project in order to use it.

If for whatever reason neither of these are an option, you can emulate the for-each loop using pre-1.5 language constructs. The most basic approach is described in Pat's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Compile this in a later version of java if you can.

If you are unable to use a later version of java for some reason just use a regular for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < xabc.length; i++) {
    int temp = xabc[i];
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing compiler compilance level in eclipse:-

1. click Windows , go to preferences.
2. select java from the options ,select compiler in drop down menu.
3. change compiler compilance level to a value 1.5 or greater.

click on the link for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/79tvV.png

Answer (score 1):

This is for eclipse.

window -> preferences -> java -> compiler -> configure project specific settings -> double click on created 'project name' -> uncheck 'use compliance from execution environment' -> then select 'compiler compliance level' to 1.5 or higher(best to choose the last level which is maximum and latest)

Done. now apply and close all. re run the program.